# PHP PDO class not found - Zend + Doctrine

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I am trying to run doctrine's orm command line tool using `doctrine-module.php orm:validate` but I keep getting `Class 'PDO' not found`. I have enabled `extension=pdo.so` and `extension=pdo_mysql.so` in the following php.ini files:

`/usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini`

`/usr/local/zend/etc-6.1.0/php.ini`

`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

However, I'm not sure why it still isn't working. My application is working, just the cli tool isn't. What are the differences between the phi.ini files (I assume the cli ini configures the cli tool) and how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, make it clear that which file your php uses for configuration.
php.ini path can be configured in compile time.

Simply run `php -i | grep ini` so you can get actual php.ini path that will be used.

Then you can write any configurations as you need into that file.